# Change IE document mode via Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change the document mode via js? The js is run as code from a bookmarklet.

I AM able to change the content mode in the meta tag, but this doesn't actually make the page render any differently. I need to be able to run js code that doesn't work in IE8 (i.e. getComputedStyle).

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
for (var i=0; i<metas.length;i++) {  
  if (metas[i].getAttribute("content") ) {
     if(metas[i].getAttribute("content")=="IE=8"){
        metas[i].setAttribute("content","IE=9"); // also tried IE=Edge
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: so you are trying to change the header after the browser used it?!

Comment: Yes, and then have it reload, I guess. I realize this probably isn't possible, but thought I'd throw it out there. I have been pleasantly surprised before.

Comment: by this code it is not possible, you need server side coding